# How do i prove this stage proving Fubini's theorem for complete measure space?(Edited)

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

I thought i proved it, but i found an error when i was revising my note.

> Let $(X,\mathfrak{M},\mu),(Y,\Sigma,\nu)$ be sigma-finite complete measure spaces.
>
> Let $\overline{\mu\times\nu}$ be the completion of $\mu\times\nu$
>
> Let $f\in L^1(\overline{\mu\times \nu})$
>
> Define $S=\{x\in X : f_x\in L^1(\nu)\}$
>
> Then, $S\in \mathfrak{M}$ and $\mu(X\setminus S)=0$

Here's what i have tried:

Since $f$ is $\mathfrak{M}\otimes\Sigma$-measurable, so is $|f|$.

Define $T=\{x\in X : |f|_x \text{ is measurable }\}$

Define $\phi(x)=\int_Y |f|_x d\nu, \forall x\in X$.

Then, by Tonelli's theorem, $\phi$ is measurable and $\mu(X\setminus T)=0$.

I thought $S=T\setminus \phi^{-1}(\infty)$, but i think it generally does not hold. That is, even if $|f|_x$ is measurable, $f_x$ may not be measurable. It's true that $S\subset T\setminus \phi^{-1}(\infty)$ but i'm not sure about the converse.

How do i prove this?

Comment: Why are you worrying about measurability? The partial function (i.e. $f(x, \cdot)$) of a measurable function is measurable.

Comment: @Giuseppe No it's not. $f$ is measurable with respect to the completion. So $f_x$ may not be measurable.

Comment: But everything is ok up to an exceptional null set. So there is an exceptional set for the $x$ in $f_x$, another for the $x$ in $\lvert f \rvert_x$, and taking the union yields an exceptional null set valid for both. I hope it is clear what I mean.

Comment: @Giuseppe Actually you are saying the question i asked, but i found your comment helpful. Since "Showing exceptional set for x in f_x is a null set" is what i needed.

Comment: That is, i found this approach of "Extending Tonelli for Complete measure space to Fubini for Complete measure space" is wrong. It should be proved by extending Fubini's theorem directly.

Comment: I am glad it helped. IMHO, those are not matters of vital importance, but that's a biased point of view.